# Can I use my email address as RabbitMQ username?

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq

Currently I am developing a Web Site based on Spring Boot which needs to be integrated with RabbitMQ.

And I just want to know that if I can use my email address as Username of RabbitMQ account.

Since email address has dot(.) and at(@) in the middle of String, I guess it's inappropriate but, it is required to implement.

So, is there a way to use email address as Username for RabbitMQ's account?

Just need this to work on CachingConnectionFactory.setUri function.

Current Code is as below.

```
@Bean
public CachingConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory(RabbitProperties config)
        throws Exception {
    CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
    connectionFactory.getRabbitConnectionFactory().setUri("amqp://test@email.com:testing@name.of.host/virtual");
    return connectionFactory;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the [RabbitMQ URI Specification](https://www.rabbitmq.com/uri-spec.html) which refers to [RFC 3986](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt). The former requires the username field of the uri to be; `*( unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims )` as defined in the latter.

In the RFC we see reserved characters include the `@` symbol;

> ```
>   reserved    = gen-delims / sub-delims
>
>  gen-delims  = ":" / "/" / "?" / "#" / "[" / "]" / "@"
>
>  sub-delims  = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
>              / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
> ```

So you'll need to use the `pct-encoded` form of those reserved characters. For example the `@` symbol would become `%40`.